# PHP: strtotime not working when time is formatted 12:00a

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a string into a timestamp using PHP's strtotime() function. This works fine when it is formatted 12:00am, however, if it is formatted 12:00a or 12:00p I get an inconsistent result.

What would be the best way to do this? I would like to convert 12:00a to a timestamp, not 12:00am, but sometimes it can be formatted 12:00am.

Comment: Why not add a "m" then?

Comment: Check if the string ends with `a` or `p`. If it does, add an `m` after it and then parse it.

Comment: Try to pass just `12:00` to `strtotime()` and append `a` or `p` with it, its a bit weird for me

Comment: `am/pm` are standard identifiers. `a/p` are not. So `strtotime` will not work with them.

Comment: _"I would like to convert 12:00a to a timestamp, not 12:00am"_ - Why? Is there a specific reason for it that you haven't told us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions - add `m` to the end of time string:

```
$str = '12:00a';
echo strtotime($str . ($str[-1] != 'm' ? 'm' : ''));
// or more strict check
echo strtotime($str . ($str[-1] == 'a' || $str[-1] == 'p' ? 'm' : ''));
```

Comment: Added a bit to make sure it's 12 hour time: strtotime($str . (($str[-1] != 'm' && ($str[-1] == 'a' OR $str[-1] == 'p')) ? 'm' : ''))

Comment: In this case there's no need to check if it is __not `m`__. See the update.

Comment: Gotcha, I like it... Thanks